# How to create dynamic interpolation maps using CartoDB?

Tags: raster, carto

I can make interpolation maps in different time sets and save it as Rasters. How can I make them dynamic using CartoDB and its time slider?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, CartoDB really only supports point data for visualizations. On top of that, the Torque visualizations don't really show changes to a single point over time, they show changes to a place by the values through multiple discrete points. Armed with that, you may be able to explode your rasters out into point tables and make it work.